# Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.net::FileReference@34f1d99 to org.restfulx.utils.RxFileReference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionscript-3

I'm learning about Working with RestfulX Model Attachments by following this link
http://dima.github.com/2009/03/19/working-with-restfulx-model-attachments.html

But I got the error when I clicked to attach a file.

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.net::FileReference@34f1d99 to org.restfulx.utils.RxFileReference.
    at rxmodelattachments.components.generated::ContactBox/fileSelected()[C:\Data\Workspace\rx_model_attachments\src\rxmodelattachments\components\generated\ContactBox.mxml:88]
    at rxmodelattachments.components.generated::ContactBox/selectFile()[C:\Data\Workspace\rx_model_attachments\src\rxmodelattachments\components\generated\ContactBox.mxml:80]

I think because of RxFileReference on these lines of code

private var file:RxFileReference;
    private function chooseFile():void {
      file = new RxFileReference("avatar");
      file.reference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
      file.reference.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectFile, false, 0, true);
      file.reference.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelBrowse, false, 0, true);
      file.reference.browse();
    }

P.S. from the link you will see they use file.addEventListener which is impossible. Cos RxFileReference doesn't have method addEventListener. So I need to use .reference to allow me to use addEventListener method.
How to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have updated **chooseFile** function

You are using

```
file.reference.addEventListener(..);
```

while link have

```
file.addEventListener(..);
```

Complete function is as from link provided in question

```
private function chooseFile():void {
      file = new RxFileReference("avatar");
      file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler, false, 0, true);
      file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectFile, false, 0, true);
      file.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelBrowse, false, 0, true);
      file.browse();
    }
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: Ah, yes.. Actually, if I directly use as the link. There is error which no method addEventListener. So I need to put .reference to use .addEventListener

Comment: i think you need to get latest lib, if still wont work! file a bug on there side, because at-least example should work as it is.